# Density plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

What is the Matlab's comparable function to Mathematica's `ListDensityPlot`? For example

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[Sin[x y/100], {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}], 
 DataRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}]
```

will produce

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: My suspicion is that there isn't one (I'm unsure, so I'm only commenting, I hope someone proves me wrong). But this is not that surprising: if you throw a stone in the woods, there's a 90% chance that it will hit a specialized Mathematica function;) You can always use something like [`histogram2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram2.html) to produce the density data, then plot that with some interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab is different than Mathematica in the sense of vectorized computations vs symbolic computation.

You could do what you'd like by defining a grid of spatial samples for x & y and then sample your function accordingly.

For example:

```
dx = 0.1;
dy = 0.1;
x = -50:dx:50;
y = -50:dy:50;
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
imagesc(sin(xx.*yy/100));
```

Comment: I know about `imagesc`. But we need a fine mesh to produce smooth image.

Comment: @Sukan if I'm not mistaken, `imshow` can do interpolation which will make your image smoother (at the cost of mildly distorting your data, but that's a conceptual thing that Mathematica can't avoid either).

Comment: @Sukan To be fair to Matlab, Mathematica needs a fine mesh as well ( seen with the option `Mesh->All`), but Matlab figures don't resample/remesh their inputs like Mathematica does.  If `imagesc` doesn't work, what about `surface(xx,yy,sin(xx.*yy/100),'EdgeColor','interp'); shading('interp');`?

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work. Still can't match the output of `ListDensityPlot` for the same mesh size though. Thanks.

Comment: for the record Mathematicas `List-Plot` varients plot the given data, there is no adaptive sampling. In the example it has only the supplied 100x100 grid to work with